# Java Inheritance. Interesting thing

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider having the piece of code:

```
public class Base {
    int a = 1;

    public int getA() {
        System.out.print("Super");
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Base base = new Sub();
        System.out.println(base.a + " " + base.getA());
        System.out.println(base.getA());
        System.out.println(base.a);
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    int a = 2;

    public int getA() {
        System.out.print("Sub");
        return a;
    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
Sub1 2
Sub2
1
```

Can somebody explain me the output? Why `System.out.println(base.a + " " + base.getA());` and `System.out.println(base.getA());System.out.println(base.a);` give different output?

I consider that the output to `System.out.println(base.a + " " + base.getA());` should be `Sub2 1`

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the examples?

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, thank you very much for editing my post. Now it looks better

Comment: This was previously answered [here][1]: 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448956/override-member-data-in-subclass-use-in-superclass-implementation

Comment: The problem you're seeing is called `hiding` since fields **don't** get overridden, so when calling `Base#a` you get `1` and when calling `Base#getA()` you get the result of the current object reference instead. More on this: [Java field hiding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10154348/1065197)

Comment: Your question is about what's on the stack when the first `println()` gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
System.out.println(base.a + " " + base.getA());
```

prints

```
Sub1 2
```

because `getA()` (and its System.out.println("Sup")) is called before the String is created and `println` finishes executing.

The steps are like this

1. `System.out.println(base.a + " " + base.getA());` is called
2. `base.getA()` is called, executing `System.out.print("Sub");` and returning `2`. At this point, `Sub` is printed to `out`.
3. A String is created as the concatenation of `base.a`, which is the value `1` and the return of **2**, which is the value `2`
4. The resulting String of **3** is printed, the String `1 2`
5. The output already contains `Sub`, then the result of **4** gets appended to that, so `Sub1 2`.

Comment: @user2654250 Which part? I've put an ordered list of execution steps so it's more clear.

Comment: @user2654250 You are welcome. Be careful when mixing method calls and String concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

> Why `System.out.println(base.a + " " + base.getA());` and `System.out.println(base.getA());System.out.println(base.a);` give different output?

In the first case you're printing `base.a` first and `base.getA()` second. In the second case you're printing `base.getA()` first and `base.a` second. So obviously the numbers will be the other way around.

Comment: sepp2k, please be more attentive, i don't think that your answer is correct.

Comment: @user2654250 And why do you think that?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct too. But I had been considering it wrong, because until Solirios Delimanolis answer thought, that the problem was with inheritance.